# Rails-less gem error, LESS not processing because gem is pointing to wrong file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rails app and using Less. I've just save my project after editing a change on a .less file, and now I'm showing an error which reads:

**Less::ParseError at /
Operation on an invalid type
  (in /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/PROJECTNAME/app/assets/stylesheets/custom_bootstrap/custom_bootstrap.less)**

There's no error in the file above, but upon a deeper look, Better Errors is showing a path to :

**() usr/local/rvmruby-2.1.1@PROJECTNAME/gems/less-2.5.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js**

The problem is that the above file doesn't exist. I think it's looking for the file that exists:

**/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@PROJECTNAME/gems/less-2.5.0/lib/less/js/lib/less/parser.js**

Is there anyway to point to that file?

Thanks ahead of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. At least, now my project is working (=

custom_bootstrap.less pre-imports a ton of custom modification files which aren't needed. Deleting these file fixed my issue.

Just for backup though, save this file elsewhere.